# Python for Flash Player

Tags: python, flash, apache-flex, air, cpython

Would it be technically possible to embed Python into a Flex/AIR application by compiling CPython code using [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/alchemy.html)?

(I'm guessing the project should be called [Flython](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Flython).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

But don't expect all the standard modules to build.  Some system calls won't translate. It would be a lot of work to port.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid you might say that.  I might be foolish enough to test the waters.

Comment: It's a great idea.  GO FOR IT . . . and LGPL the results when you're done.  ;)